# NSMutableArray Sort Task

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, nsmutablearray, nsarray

i have `NSMutableArray` contains `NSArray` Objects, it looks like this

```
(
    "2012-10-10 13:13:29 +0000",
    cc5772389efc1f93bedaab872bad542a1c8432af,
    "{\n    size             = {360, 480}\n    CGImage.size     = {480, 360}\n    imageOrientation = UIImageOrientationRight\n}"
),
    (
    "2012-10-10 13:13:37 +0000",
    6c09d99f940af8e7d1d1392d28abee2133b7ac75,
    "{\n    size             = {360, 480}\n    CGImage.size     = {480, 360}\n    imageOrientation = UIImageOrientationRight\n}"
),
    (
    "2012-10-10 13:13:19 +0000",
    0165776bd9e96e640c905471ddb8630c22a8911c,
    "{\n    size             = {360, 480}\n    CGImage.size     = {480, 360}\n    imageOrientation = UIImageOrientationRight\n}"
)
```

each `NSArray` object contains `NSDate` object at the first index, i want to sort this`NSMutableArray` from the older to the newest.

any idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use NSMutableArray's [`-sortUsingComparator:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000138-BABCBFFC).

> `sortUsingComparator:`
>   Sorts the array using the comparison method specified by a given [NSComparator](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_DataTypes/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSComparator) Block.
>
> `- (void)sortUsingComparator:(NSComparator)cmptr`
>   *Parameters*  `cmptr` A [comparator](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_DataTypes/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSComparator) block.

```
[array sortUsingComparator: ^(NSArray *array1, NSArray *array2) {
    NSDate *date1 = [array1 objectAtIndex:0];
    NSDate *date2 = [array2 objectAtIndex:0];
    return [date1 compare:date2];
}];
```

to reverse the order, you can simply return `[date2 compare:date1]`

Answer (score 0):

use [-sortedArrayUsingFunction:context:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html)

```
NSInteger dateSort(id obj1, id obj2, void *context)
{
    NSData *date1 = [obj1 objectAtIndex:0] ;
    NSData *date2 = [obj2 objectAtIndex:0] ;
    return [date1 compare:date2];
}
NSArray *sortedArray = [array sortedArrayUsingFunction:dateSort context:NULL];
```